# updating reducer causes removing old state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have the following:

```
types.ts
export interface Window {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    target?: string;
}

export interface WindowState {
    windows: Window[];
}

export const ADD_TARGET = 'ADD_TARGET'

interface AddTargetAction {
  type: typeof ADD_TARGET
  id: string,
  target: string
}

export type WindowActionTypes =  AddTargetAction

actions.ts

export function AddTarget (target: string, id: string): WindowActionTypes {
  return {
    type: ADD_TARGET,
    id: id,
    target: target
  }
}


REducers.ts

const initialState: WindowState = {
    windows: [{
        id: uuidv4(),
        name: "Computer",
        target: ""
    }]
}

export function WindowReducer (
  state = initialState,
  action: WindowActionTypes
): WindowState {
  switch (action.type) {
      case ADD_TARGET: 
          return {
              ...state,
               windows: state.windows.filter(user => user.id === action.id).map(user => ({ ...user, target: action.target }))
          }
      default:
          return state;
  }
}
```

where I dispatch a function providing the id of the user and then it will fetch it from the list and update it its target with the payload, but somehow when I use that function, the old state which was in my initial state and other is removed and I only have the user which I fetched its target and updated it, anybody know a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is you are using a filter which will return only matched user.

You should write it like this

```
state.windows.map(user => if(user.id === action.id) { return ({ ...user, target: action.target })) } else { return user });
```

Comment: thanks mate! it worked! another thing, what if I have a counter in the interface Window and I want to increment it, but with the same logic, like I need to find a user by id and then increment that counter?

Comment: yeah. same way as the target is updated. just do something like this, counter: user.counter + 1